# Is there any way to calculate gensim WmdSimilarity faster

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, sentence-similarity

I am working with gensim WmdSimilarity. I followed [this tutorial](https://markroxor.github.io/gensim/static/notebooks/WMD_tutorial.html). But for a pre-trained model, it took 5-6 seconds for each output. I found [some other implementation](https://github.com/src-d/wmd-relax) of calculating WMD (Word Mover Distance) but I'm not sure about using it with pre-trained W2V

Comment: How large are your texts? (Also, was your "some other implementation" link supposed to go somewhere?)

Comment: I've experimented with 20 sentences. But I need to do it for 10000 sentences. I have updated the link.

Comment: How large is each individual text? (WMD execution time grows very fast with respect to the number of words per text.)

Comment: Also, are you saying it takes 5-6 seconds for a single-text to single-text calculation, or for the completion of some other batch of operations?